# Issues with referencing experimental light class

Tags: unity, lighting

I am trying to reference a Light2D component on a GameObject but I get the following error:

```
'The type or namespace name 'Universal' does not exist in the namespace 'UnityEngine.Experimental.Rendering'.
```

I have confirmed that I have v10.2.2 of the Universal RP package in package manager. I have also attempted regenerating all csproj files as well as deleting the Library folder and reopening Unity. I also have the library reference to 'UnityEngine.Experimental.Rendering.Universal' in my script.

Comment: If you remove that `using` line, right-click "Light2D", and choose "Quick Actions & Refactorings", what `using` options does Visual Studio suggest?

Comment: @Kevin I'm using VS Code. I don't have that option. There are no suggested fixes that pop up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using an assembly definition asset make sure you add references to the universal pipeline assets under the Assembly Definition References portion.